# Converting a single dictionary value in to a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets take dictionary

r = {u'a': 'john', u'b': 'ABA Design House , Developing Minds Foundation , Food Network South Beach Wine & Food Festival', u'c': 'give'}

I want to convert it to:

r = {u'a': 'john', u'b': **['ABA Design House', 'Developing Minds Foundation', 'Food Network South Beach Wine & Food Festival']**, u'c': 'give'}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use in-built method split()

```
>>> r[u'b'] = r[u'b'].split(',')
>>> r
    {u'a': 'john', u'c': 'give', u'b': ['ABA Design House ', ' Developing Minds Foundation ', ' Food Network South Beach Wine & Food Festival']}
```

In case you are uncomfortable with the leading/trailing spaces use the strip() method after you split

```
>>> r[u'b']=[x.strip() for x in r[u'b'].split(',')]
>>> r
{u'a': 'john', u'c': 'give', u'b': ['ABA Design House', 'Developing Minds Foundation', 'Food Network South Beach Wine & Food Festival']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to do that for every comma-separated value in your dictionary:

```
for k, v in r.items():
    if "," in v:
        r[k] = [item.strip() for item in v.split(",")]
```